# CMMotionActivityManager - authorizationStatus "refresh"

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am checking the authorizationStatus() of CMMotionActivityManager when "Fitness Tracking" status is disabled in phone's Settings > Privacy > Motion & Fitness. I get a correct status of "restricted" for system wide restrictions.

When I enable the "Fitness Tracking", and bring my app back to foreground from background, the authorizationStatus() still returns "restricted". If I swipe-out/terminate the application and relaunch, it then changes the authorization status.

Is there a way to refresh the authorizationStatus() when bringing the app from background to foreground.

Thanks!

Comment: No, changing the authorization status in settings does not crash the app. I have to manually terminate the application to launch fresh.

Comment: Well in my opinion (and probably yours) if the user changes from restricted to granted and you do not crash and if you get stale info when you ask again about the authorization status, that is a bug and you should report it. I would add, however, that you should never just believe what the authorization status tells you; nothing really happens until you "tickle" the system by _trying to use the activity manager_. Are you doing that?

Comment: In other words you should start updates or query activity _no matter what_ result you get from the authorization status call. If you are not authorized, nothing happens and no harm done. (You will get an error in good order on the completion handler.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried "tickling" by starting the activity update regardless of the authorization status. It still doesn't refresh the status. It does appear to be a bug. Let me report it and see what Apple has to say. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I cannot reproduce your results. In my testing, when you change the authorization in Settings, the app _does_ crash, we relaunch when we switch back to it, and the authorization status test gives the correct result. — However, I tested only with authorized and denied, not restricted. Perhaps if there is a bug it is confined to restricted.

Comment: Here's a screencast showing that we crash in the background and authorization status works correctly. I repeat, though, that I have not checked to see whether this is true of restrictions as well. It may be that this works as intended. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9mqrace7fqs3n4/RPReplay_Final1571321489.MP4?dl=0

Comment: hey, Matt, AG is right, CMMotionActivityManager is giving the wrong status for the case of Restricted even if you start activity or query for past activity. The only way to get correct status is to relaunch app manually. It's a bug it should be reported on apple support.

Comment: Just confirming that I too am seeing the same results as AG (of the status not being "refreshed"). Since the app doesn't crash when the global motion permission is toggled, I think I'm going to just show a dialogue telling the user to restart the app on his or her own. Of course, the best UX will depend upon the implementation / product.

Comment: Hey People,Do someone found a work around for this issue???Does this issue still exists in apple??@AG

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and this behavior happens only **before** the user grants permission for motion data to your app. Once your app has given permission the first time THEN if the motion permission is toggled on device level, iOS will terminate your app (but if and only if your app has given permission at some point). So once you give permission your app will appear in the motion permission list (see image below) and if so then iOS will terminate when the switch is toggled.

[image]